# Twitter api search query for multiple accounts and words

Tags: api, twitter, sttwitterapi

How can I create a twitter search query for multiple accounts based on multiple words? 
For example: Consider two accounts: @hero1 and @hero2. I want all tweets from hero1 containing words 'super' or 'action' and tweets from hero2 containing word 'enemy' or a hashtag '#great'. How can I achieve this in one search query. I am able to search for a single account and single keyword but the multiple case is not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Currently my api call looks like:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3Ahero1+super+action&count=10&include_entities=true
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you've written so far?

Comment: @TerenceEden I have updated the question with a sample call I am using.

Comment: Your code only shows you searching for `from:hero1 super action`

Comment: @TerenceEden https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3Ahero1+super+action+AND+from%3Ahero2+enemy+#great&count=10&include_entities=true . This is what I was trying to do, but its not working, to be exact, I dont know if this is the correct way to achieve what I need. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The [advanced search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced) doesn't allow the sort of query that you want in a single request.

You will have to call two separate searches:

`super or action from:hero1` and the `enemy or #great from:hero2`

Comment: Oh! Actually these account handles and words are to be dynamically added from backend and therefore there will be multiple data and now it seems I will have to call it in a loop. Too sad! Anyways thanks mate!